# Disable .AspNetCore.Antiforgery Cookie

Tags: cookies, .net-core

Is there any way to prevent the **.AspNetCore.Antiforgery** Cookie from being created in Asp.Net Core 2?

From my understanding services.addmvc internally calls AddAntiforgery and I cannot seem to find any way to prevent this?

The reason why this is important is because I cannot set any cookies before the user gives his consent and the .AspNetCore.Antiforgery cookie is set by default.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

OK, I found a solution.
If you add this line to ConfigureServices in Startup.cs the cookie will never be created:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => { options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.Zero;});
```

Comment: This is horrible, you have to add the thing to specify that you don't want the thing in a horrible way. When I'm programming I think: "What would Ken Thompson do?" This is absolutely not what he would do.
Tyvm anyways this helped

Comment: As a solution it's not great anyway as the server still sends a response cookie to the browser, which subsequently doesn't store it because the cookie has already expired.

Comment: I can't believe this is still the only way to do this in .Net6. You probably also want `o.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true;` in .Net6 as well, otherwise it can cause issues if you plan to allow embedding and controlling the x-frame-options / CSP yourself.

Answer (score 1):

There are several options to disable automatic generation of antiforgery tokens and cookies from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-5.0):

Explicitly disable antiforgery tokens with the `asp-antiforgery` attribute (works well for me):

```html
<form method="post" asp-antiforgery="false">
    ...
</form>
```

The form element is opted-out of Tag Helpers by using the Tag Helper `! opt-out symbol`:

```html
<!form method="post">
    ...
</!form>
```

Remove the `FormTagHelper` from the view. The `FormTagHelper` can be removed from a view by adding the following directive to the Razor view:

```html
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding this to Startup.cs worked for me:

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(o=>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

I got it from here: https://www.talkingdotnet.com/disable-antiforgery-token-validation-globally-asp-net-core-razor-pages/

I needed this for an intranet where a certain form needed to be kept open until a long real-world task was completed.