# How to disable the antiforgery token check in ASP.NET MVC Core 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0, antiforgerytoken

I am trying to avoid "AntiForgery" checking as it always fails when hosted from the 3rd party server. I am using ASP.NET Core 2.0 MVC application.

I added this option in the `ConfigureServices` function:

```
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddRazorPagesOptions( options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AuthorizeFolder("/Account/Manage");
        options.Conventions.AuthorizePage("/Account/Logout");
        options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    } );
```

But still I am getting this exception.

> System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key {6fb328e7-4808-4b5d-b7dc-870d126e5ca4} was not found in the key ring.

Am I missing anything ?

Comment: "it always fails when hosted from the 3rd party server" - perhaps it's a better idea to fix *that* issue instead of disabling a useful security feature. What is happening on the other server that causes it to break?

Comment: This entire token system and antiforgery system is not working when hosted from third party IIS server. I have opened a bug as well as submitted the logs. Since this is test, I simply want to remove antiforgery system from the application. I did some research and added that line of code in configureservice function. But still the application is checking for the token. Not sure how to disable it. Any advice?

Comment: Is your application using *only* RazorPages? If you're using the full version of ASP.NET Core's MVC functionality or something else then it won't be under `AddRazorPagesOptions` but will be elsewhere.

Answer (score 7):

Add the `IgnoreAntiforgeryToken` attribute (Order must > 1000) to the razor page model:

For example:

```
namespace CWACpch.Pages
{
    [IgnoreAntiforgeryToken(Order = 2000)]
    public class CreateOrderModel : PageModel
    {
```

Comment: That worked - it does feel like a "work around" which then could expose an application to a security flaw. However, I wanted a demo to run, where (as above) a third party does the form POST.

Answer (score 3):

Been looking around for how to disable the cookie, setting the Order does not seem to help for me, and trying to set it to all pages via below also did not work for me.

```
options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
```

I eventually found article below which helps per deleting the cookie locally, at least. Add the line below in the Startup.cs
[Disable .AspNetCore.Antiforgery Cookie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411402/disable-aspnetcore-antiforgery-cookie)

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => { options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.Zero;});
```

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding you don't have to disable any thing.
 By default if you use asp net tag helper to create form element it will put anti forgery token

It is upto you to validate anti forgery token by the use [ValidateAntiforgeryToken] annotation in action method or globally define configuration to ValidateAntiforgeryToken which will make  system  to try validate anti forgery token

If you have not configured system as mentioned about the system won't validate  anti forgery token and won't be problem for your situation

Comment: I have this data annotation ([ValidateAntiforgeryToken]) everywhere in the code. I need it when I go to production. But during testing, I want to suppress the 'Anti Forgery Validation' check. So I added this line (options.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());) But still the application gives me this exception. (The antiforgery token could not be decrypted.
 System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException:). My question is why is it still checking ?

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone else struggles with this in NET 6;

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => { options.SuppressXFrameOptionsHeader = true; });
```