# Cookieless ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, cookies, antiforgerytoken, asp.net-core-3.1

I am developing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 application. I am not using any kind of authentication, session data/logic and form elements. I see the **.AspNetCore.Antiforgery** cookie in my in my developer console, although I did not call `services.AddAntiforgery()` in my `Startup` class.

I found [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50411402/1865613) with a very unsatisfying accepted answer, since this cookie will still be sent to the client (pointed out by hemp's comment).

So my question is: How do I completely remove this CSFR cookie?

Comment: What's the motivation for doing this?

Comment: @KirkLarkin My motivation for doing this is to host a website without cookies. I think it's a nice feature, isn't it?

Comment: asp.net core tags add it by default -> you need sth like this `<form method="post" asp-antiforgery="false">`

Comment: while its a noble goal to have a site without cookies, the Antiforgery cookie is a security cookie that should not be removed imho.

Comment: @Charles The only form I have is the search input. There are no writing/modification processes in the whole website. It only displays plain data. From my research, the antiforgerytoken is not necessary in this case. Am I right?

Comment: I would suggest  using the `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` which will require an anti forgery token only for unsafe requests. As long as the connection is secure your site wil not pass a token for `GET,HEAD,OPTIONS,TRACE` requests https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.autovalidateantiforgerytokenattribute?view=aspnetcore-3.1. Generally I would not omit the `Anti Forgery` but if you must at least have a small backup.

Comment: There are a number of ways to opt out of request verification: https://www.learnrazorpages.com/security/request-verification#opting-out

Comment: @KirkLarkin Please think that you have a razor page app with web API controllers for embedded devices. Razor pages are for UI and API is for devices. Since embedded devices using bearer token to authenticate, there is no need for a cookie like that. So, enable it for Razor Pages and disable it for web API controllers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Asp.Net Core adds the anti forgery token automatically to the `form`.

You need `<form method="post" asp-antiforgery="false">`, this will omit the anti forgery token.

Even though this documentation of Microsoft says how to prevent Cross Site.
There is a lot of material on how to ignore it -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#aspnet-core-antiforgery-configuration

> *All the appropriate techniques are listed in the docs.*

Comment: But the question asks how to disable the cookie not the token sent within the form. Even though there is no form or even no view generated, the token still is transferred by the server.

Comment: I am not familiar with what you are talking, could you please provide more info?

Comment: The question says a cookie is sent by the server. The name of the cookie is `.AspNetCore.Antiforgery` the method you propose does not remove or prevent the cookie. Applying the method in your answer only prevents the hidden input field to be inserted into the form. Your answer does not answer the question properly.

Comment: I am sorry i just tested this. No cookie is sent to the browser. I used chrome https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/storage/cookies. Please provide evidence. Also make sure to delete the previous cookie that was created when the anti forgery was true. I am more than glad to update the answer. I just cannot reproduce what you are saying. You are correct though if there was a previous cookie until it expires it is still there.You have to manually delete it. Although your backend does not require it. **Also feel free to answer this question yourself**.

Comment: Sorry. That was my mistake. I was testing with Postman. I was sure I have cleared the cookies. But failed to do so. So I was seeing the stored cookie. Thank you for your reply. After testing with PowerShell I saw that no cookie was sent.

Answer (score 4):

As panoskarajohn says,

> Asp.Net Core adds the anti forgery token automatically to the form.

Because it is a tag helper. So you can avoid the tag helper to stop the anti-forgery token. You can use the tag helper ‘!’ opt-out symbol

```
<!form  method=”post”>
    …
</!form >
```

Also, You can avoid the tag helper for the entire page.

```
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.FormTagHelper,  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
```

Check this link http://blog.vivensas.com/cross-site-request-forgery-in-asp-net-core-formtaghelper/#avoidAntiForgeryToken