# Is AntiforgeryToken mandatory in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, antiforgerytoken

So I have this really weird problem here. I have this small page (a razor page) used to collect adhesions from exhibitors to our local trade fair. It is a really simple page that collect basic info like name, phone, email and so on. Finally everything is posted to the server where the info is stored and a confirmation email is sent to the requesters.

Now I have not used anywhere the `@Html.AntiforgeryToken` helper (not really required at least as I thought about it) but, nevertheless, when I Post the info I got an exception in my log files that tell me:

> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel|Connection id `0HLSFHDUIPON3`,
>   Request id `0HLSFHDUIPON3:00000001`: An unhandled exception was thrown
>   by the application. System.InvalidOperationException: The antiforgery
>   token could not be decrypted. --->
>   System.Security.Cryptography.CryptographicException: The key
>   {dc285e40-0619-4182-a37c-20c1899a2e26} was not found in the key ring.

It seems like I need to add this `@Html.AntiforgeryToken` helper to my page. Or there is something that I haven't fully grasped as I am a novice in this application context (ASP.NET Core)

Note that I am forced to use ASP.NET Core 2.0 because our ISP doesn't support yet the latest version, so I don't know if it something that has been fixed in following versions.

This is a redacted form code:

```
<form id="form1" class="form-horizontal" method="post">
    <div class="form-group headerSection">
        <table class="tableStandard">
            <tr class="rowInterline"><td /><td /></tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="labelPrompt">
                    <label for="partecipation.Name">Firm's name</label>
                </td>
                <td class="editInput">
                    <input type="text" asp-for="partecipation.Name" class="editBoxUpperCase" />
                    <span asp-validation-for="partecipation.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            .... a lot more tr but everything the same
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="checkbox" asp-for="partecipation.Privacy" Text="" />&nbsp;
            <a class="horizSpace" asp-page='/Privacy'>Privacy consent</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Send the partecipation request" class="outline-btn info btn-lg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: asp.net core adds it by default -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59555441/cookieless-asp-net-core/59555721#59555721

Comment: @panoskarajohn added the form code

Comment: Ahhh that _asp-antiforgery="false"_ seems promising.

Comment: I believe the above question link provides all the info you require. `form` is a tag helper for asp.net core and adds the anti forgery by default see the answer -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/59555721/3902958

Comment: @marcus, I hope is link will help you http://blog.vivensas.com/cross-site-request-forgery-in-asp-net-core-formtaghelper/