# How to handle default antiforgery cookie in ASP.NET Core 6?

Tags: .net-core, iis, .net-6.0, antiforgerytoken

I published an ASP.NET Core 6 web app to an IIS 10 server.

Apparently the site produces an antiforgery cookie:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get rid of it or rename it?

I tried:

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.HeaderName = "heres-a-cookie";
});
```

But that just added another cookie

The following also didn't help - it renamed the identity cookie.

```
builder.Services.AddAntiforgery(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.Name = "heres-a-cookie";
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50411402/disable-aspnetcore-antiforgery-cookie

Comment: @AjayKelkar Have you try it ? If use `options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.Zero;`, the application will not work.

Comment: What effect do you want to achieve? After I tested it, I found that the information is stored in the cookie after logging in. Ajay's suggestion is to set the expiration date, so I think it is meaningless.

Comment: @Jason either disabling this particular cookie or renaming it will work for me. I just don't want to show that I'm using asp.net core

Answer (score 0):

```
services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(o=>
{
    o.Conventions.ConfigureFilter(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
});
```

try above.

Comment: unfortunetly no luck